# git add regex example

Tags: git

I am trying to add part of a commit using

```
git add -p
```

I chose the regex option

```
/ - search for a hunk matching the given regex
```

The patch contains these lines

```
+      AMFObject obj2;
+      AMFObjectProperty p;
+      AVal redirect;
```

But git doesn't seem to find it

```
search for regex? redirect
No hunk matches the given pattern
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue was that this patch affected more than one file.

I needed to chose

```
d - do not stage this hunk nor any of the later hunks in the file
```

until reaching correct file, then regex will work.